# expo camera in react native draws image fliped on screen only iphone

Tags: react-native, expo, tensorflow.js

[Camera Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5P65.jpg)

image in back is scaled twice on style.
just twice not minus.
i use expo-camera and tensorflow js camerawithTensors.
how can i controll middle image?

Comment: how does your camera component look like?

Comment: camera image is right and left reversal. click Camera Image link

Comment: i meant the code. i am guessing that there are additional views within the `<Camera />` tags or that there may be issues with your styling, but i wouldnt be sure until i can see your code.

Comment: oh i get it , i don't use just Camera. use cameraWithTensor in tensorflow.js. and that that's style code is   camera: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: 2,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 0,
  }

Comment: i found which code make that result. it's updatePreview() in tfjs-react-native-API. but removing that code is just stop rendering